# Connecting PHP and SQL Server using WAMP

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

I am trying to connect my PHP with SQL Server. I have to go to the field to test it, so I was configuring a laptop with the necessary settings. In the desktop I currently work at, the connection works properly. But in the laptop, it won't connect. Here is the code I am using:

```
$serverName = "server"; //serverName\instanceName

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DB", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I have placed the .dlls in the ext file and I have written the extension in the php.ini but somehow it still won't work. This is the error I am getting:

```
Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Read the error, it looks like you need to download the SQL Server client on your laptop: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

Comment: The thing is I already have it

Comment: Consider using [PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) for more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065#SNAC

This is the answer. I downloaded the Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client and everything worked like a charm. I searched high and low for this link so now I share it here in hopes to help anyone who is looking for it like me.

Comment: There are number of products to download but there is no product with name Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client. Which product you downloaded to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

@plasmy, thanks for this. I also have searched all over to get this working. The download link on top of the page gives you a text file with instructions on how to download the file, which is seriously wtf.  The direct link for the native client is here:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648&clcid=0x409